# Add custom web application/page which uses files from other folders

Tags: 2013, javascript, master-page, custom-masterpage, html

I've created a JavaScript web browser game. The HTML page, `Game.html`, within folder `Game` references several other JS/jQuery/CSS files stored in sub folders.

I simply want to add the `Game` folder, which includes the `Game.html` file and all of its related files to SharePoint 2013 as a page. That way people can play the game on SP 2013.

[image]

I've tried the following:

- Clicked `Add Page`. This gives me the Master Page and only allows me to add web parts. So I tried adding a Content Editor Web Part and tried to reference the `Game.html` page, but then I can't reference the rest of the needed JavaScript.
- Then I mapped my drive directly to the server and uploaded my `Game` folder to the server. From there, I created a Master Page of `Game.html` in Design Manager... this did not work.

Is there a simple way to add my `Game.html` page to SP 2013 and have it reference all of its required JS files and actually run the game?

Thanks

---

**Edit**: Okay, here's what I did:

1) I uploaded all assets to `http://server/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx`, including main `Game.html` file, and supporting images and JS files.

2) Changed all references in `Game.html` to match the same folder that Game is in:

```
    <script src="http://Server/SiteAssets/createjs.js"></script>
    <script src="http://Server/SiteAssets/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://Server/SiteAssets/jquery.js"></script>
etc...
```

3) Went to `Settings -> Add a page`, which is now at `http://Server/Pages/Game.aspx`.

4) Added Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) to new Page, titled `Game`. Edited the CEWP to get the `Game.html` file located in `SiteAssets`.

5) `Game.html` seems to render okay:

[image]

However, when I submit my name in the text box, it's supposed to run the JavaScript game. But it's not working. I know it's running JavaScript because I did:

Game.html: `<body onload="test()">`

Game.html: `function test() { alert("working"); }` Outputs *"working".*

There's no console output error. And the jQuery and rest of the code seems to render for a second, flicker, and then return to the static HTML...

Any thoughts?

Comment: add the virtual directory to your sharepoint site and convert it to an application, so the virtual path to it works, then have it referenced anywhere in your sharepoint site.

Comment: @Mike How do I convert it to an app? Google search `sharepoint 2013 conversion to application` doesn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: Now that I think about it, @tyshock's solution would work better.

Comment: The only obvious thing I can think of is that a single page should have only one html tag and one body tag.  Your embedded Game.html doc should not have <html> or <body>, as SharePoint's masterpage already has those tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a one-off implementation, you could put the supporting files in a doc library ('Site Assets' would be a good one), Then, use the Content Editor Web Part route that you described above with the relative references within the 'Game.html' that point to those supporting file locations.

Comment: Just a simple one-off. How would I add my `Game.html` main page as a page within SharePoint? Would I just create a generic page, and then create a Content Editor Web part and embed? But then I can't reference more than one JS file.

Comment: In your 'Game.html', you can have multiple <script> tags that each pull in a js file.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try. Is there a way for me to enable `explorer view`? I don't want to upload each file one by one.

Comment: Tyshock please see my update above.